# How to limit number of threads created for spring controller

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

how can we restrict the number of threads/instances created for a Spring Controller. I want to restrict the number of request for a controller to 50 and queue-up the all remaining requests that can be served when other running threads are available.

We are using Spring MVC (3.0.x-RELEASE) version.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depends on where the application is running. For example if it's on Tomcat you can configure the Tomcat thread pool.

Comment: Note that the number of threads is unrelated to the number of instances. A controller, by default, is a singleton: the same, unique instance, is used concurrently by all the threads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to limit the number of concurrent thread calling a method on spring controller. I am using weblogic but want to avoid any server specific setting, is there anything we can do in Spring itself to queue-up the threads?

Comment: It is done in application server configuration not spring configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vipin. Can you let me know the application server configuration for the spring controller to restrict the number of threads.